# How do I count the number of rows that have a value in column "A", but have a different value in column "B" using Linq

Tags: c#, linq, datatable

Sry for bad english...

DataTable example

```
| ID_UEH      | ID_F   |  
|......1......|...10...|  
|......1......|...11...|  
|......2......|...10...|  
|......2......|...12...|  
|......3......|...10...|  
|......3......|...13...|
```

I want to make a function that checks if there is a line with followed specification:
- different value in column 'ID_UEH', but identical values ​​in column 'ID_F'

i tryed this:

```cs
(from rowA in DataTableA.Select()  
 join rowB in DataTableA.Select()  
  on rowA["ID_F"] equals rowB["ID_F"]
where rowA["ID_UEH"] != rowB["ID_UEH"]).Count()
```

and the code return 0

Then i try this:

```cs
(from rowA in DataTableA.Select()  
 join rowB in DataTableA.Select()  
  on rowA["ID_F"] equals rowB["ID_F"]
where rowA["ID_UEH"] != rowB["ID_UEH"] &&
      rowA["ID_F"]   == rowB["ID_F"]).Count()
```

and the code return 6 (DataTableA.Rows.Count = 6)

Then they asked me to hurry, and i did this:

```cs
int numRows = 0;  
foreach (DataRow rowA in DataTableA.Select())
{
    numRows = tabela.Select(  
    "ID_UEH <> "+Convert.ToInt32(rowA["ID_UEH"]) + " AND " +  
    "ID_F= " + Convert.ToInt32(rowA["ID_F"])  
                                       ).Length;  
    if (numRows > 1)
       break;
}
```

and code return what i want.

My question is, what i did wrong?

Comment: What's the correct answer for your given example? Can you write a logic statement to determine the result?

Comment: @KirkBroadhurst: The correct answer is 3 since there are only three rows with equal `ID_F` all with the value 10 and all with different `ID_UEH` values(1,2,3).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason why the join doesn't work is: your are joining with the same table so you get 12 rows(6+6 and all have a "counterpart" with the same `ID_UEH` value). So the correct result of 3 is also doubled.

**Edit**: I assume this is what you need, more readable than my first approach below:

```
var rows = dataTableA.AsEnumerable();
int count = rows.Count(r1 => rows
                .Any(r2 => r1.Field<int>("ID_F")   == r2.Field<int>("ID_F")
                        && r1.Field<int>("ID_UEH") != r2.Field<int>("ID_UEH")));
```

<strike>Here is the LINQ which gives you the correct result. However, it is not very readable:</strike>

```
int count =  dataTableA.AsEnumerable()
.GroupBy(r => r.Field<int>("ID_F"))
.Sum(g =>
{
    if (g.Count() == 1)
        return 0;
    var allIDUEH = g.Select(r => r.Field<int>("ID_UEH"));
    return allIDUEH.Count(ueh1 => allIDUEH.Any(ueh2 => ueh1 != ueh2));
});
```

Stay with your loop.... if it works, since it does something different than what you have described.

Answer (score 0):

```
var c = DataTableA.AsEnumerable()
                  .GroupBy(r=>r.Field<int>("ID_F"))
                  .Where(g=>g.Count()>1 &&
                            g.GroupBy(r=>r.Field<int>("ID_UEH"))
                             .Where(a=>a.Count()>1).Count() > 1)
                  .Count();
```

Comment: That's just getting the count of groups.  I would think he'd want the sum of the rows in all of those groups that meet the condition.  This is fairly close to that though.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
var q = (from r in DataTableA.AsEnumerable()
        group r by r.Field<int>("ID_F") into gr 
        let count = gr.Select(g => g.Field<int>("ID_UEH")).Distinct().Count()
        select count > 1 ? count : 0).Sum();
```